# Encrypt Excel spreadsheet epplus powershell

Tags: powershell, encryption, epplus

Do you know how to encrypt an existing xlsx file with Epplus in Powershell? I´ve been looking on how to do that with no luck. That´s what I have so far:

```
# Load EPPlus
$DLLPath = "C:\temp\excel test\ExcelModule\EPPlus.dll"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($DLLPath)

# Create Excel File
$ExcelPackage = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage 
$Worksheet = $ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.

# Encryption
$ExcelPackage.File = "C:\temp\disable.xlsx"
$ExcelPackage.Encryption.Algorithm = 
[OfficeOpenXml.EncryptionAlgorithm]::AES256
$ExcelPackage.Encryption.IsEncrypted = $true
$ExcelPackage.Encryption.Password = 'Excel'
$ExcelPackage.Save()
```

Comment: Are you saying what you have is not working? This is really less of a PowerShell code issue, which is what we are here to help with  vs an understanding of how to use EPPlus, or am I missing your point.  Even their own docs show very limited info on the encryption process, at least from my quick read of it thus far.

Answer (score 1):

***I've never used this DLL before.***

I use other tools for encryption.

So spent some time on it today and the sample below works. Peaked thru the DLL using ---

> dotPeek Free .NET Decompiler by JetBrains
>   https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download

--- to see what I was working with. After that, created sample and did the following...

Dynamically ---

1. create a new xlsx
2. Scan a folder for file types and added that to the file
3. Encrypt the file
4. Save the file

Opening the file with Excel will prompt for the password. The script...
Using Add-Type or Import-Module using the path to the .DLL both worked.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -Path 'D:\Downloads\epplus.4.5.3.1\lib\net40\EPPlus.dll'

# Import-Module 'D:\Downloads\epplus.4.5.3.1\lib\net40\EPPlus.dll'

$pkg = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage('E:\temp\output.xlsx')

Get-ChildItem "E:\Temp\*.png" | 
ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.BaseName
    $ws = $pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add($name)

    $image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName)
    $picture = $ws.Drawings.AddPicture($name, $image)
    $picture.From.Column = 1
    $picture.From.Row = 1
    $image.Dispose()
}

# Encryption
$pkg.Encryption.Algorithm = [OfficeOpenXml.EncryptionAlgorithm]::AES256
$pkg.Encryption.IsEncrypted = $true
$pkg.Encryption.Password = 'Excel'

$pkg.Save()
$pkg.Dispose()

Start-Process -FilePath 'Excel.exe' -ArgumentList 'E:\temp\output.xlsx'
```

So, really not much different than what you are doing.